# Saving new records filtered by "unique" in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query that runs everytime a user logins. **Since this query regards information the user might have *third-party updated* recently** I thought it would be a good idea to turn the `user_id + information` combo in the table unique. As so, everytime a user tried to save new information it would only save the one information I already didn't have. So, the first query being

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ("1","cake"),("1","pie"),("1","bedsheets")
```

And as the user logins a second time and it being

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ("1","cake"),("1","pie"),("1","bedsheets"),("1","chocolate")
```

It would only save `("1","chocolate")` because (id,info) being an unique pair all other would not be inserted. I came upon the realization they all fail if only one fails. So my question is: is there any way to override this operation? Or do I have to query the db first to filter the information I already have? tyvm...

Comment: Use thisI 
NSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES ("1","cake"),("1","pie"),("1","bedsheets"),("1","chocolate");

Comment: @BerndBuffen Sweet mate! I knew this wasn't that much of a stupid question. Please answer, do not comment, so I can approve it :)

Comment: When you use the IGNORE Keyword, so every errors, in the execution are ignored. Example: if you have a duplicate or PRIMARY key error while executing a INSERT Statement, so it will ignored and the execution is not aborted.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the IGNORE Keyword, so every errors, in the execution are ignored. Example: if you have a duplicate or PRIMARY key error while executing a INSERT Statement, so it will ignored and the execution is not aborted

Use this:

```
I NSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES ("1","cake"),("1","pie"),("1","bedsheets"),("1","chocolate");
```